# Question closed as duplicate of deleted question

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, deleted-questions

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/276989/any-ideas-for-a-funny-joke-to-play-on-person-who-will-be-using-my-computer-tod) has been closed as an exact duplicated of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/126173/april-fools-jokes). However, the latter question has been "deleted for purposes of moderation."

Shouldn't the first question be deleted too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

And if you do see other such cases, but you don't have the reputation (10k) to vote to delete, feel free to flag for moderator attention and point out the sinkhole happening.